# Missing Null Keyword Oracle 12C

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, oracle12c

```
ALTER TABLE READINGS 
     ADD( JSON_COL CLOB 
     CONSTRAINT con_jos_colm CHECK (JSON_COL IS JSON));
```

I'm trying to run this on Oracle 12.1.0.1.0 (which is suppose to support JSON) but getting this error

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword
00908. 00000 -  "missing NULL keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: no, that's a column level constraint and perfectly valid

Comment: Already tried it, still same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm trying to run this on Oracle **12.1.0.1.0**

JSON support was introduced with 12.1.0.**2**, so your version doesn't support that.

[Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2) New Features](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12102.htm#NEWFT505)

Comment: Is there any way to use it in my current version ?

Comment: @TheWizardOfCode: If you want to use the JSON functions as well, then no, you can't (You have to upgrade to 12.1.0.2). You can always store it as a "plain" `CLOB` - but you still won't have any JSON functions available.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to upgrade it.

Comment: @TheWizardOfCode: note that 12.1.0.2 is currently only available as the enterprise edition